# UIButton highlight setting won't stick

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

There sure are a lot of UIButton questions here, and I was hoping to find the answer to this, but nothing quite like this particular issue.

I have a few buttons, and I can call `button.highlighted = YES;` for any button when the program runs and it shows up highlighted.

I thought I could then use this same technique to set a button's highlight state to YES after it pressed, and then set it to NO after another button is pressed. This way, the current selection remains highlighted.

For example:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    if (button.tag==1)
    {
        self.button1.highlighted=YES;
        self.button2.highlighted=NO;
        // do other program stuff here
    }

    if (button.tag==2)
    {
        self.button2.highlighted=YES;
        self.button1.highlighted=NO;
        // do other program stuff here
    }
}
```

Even though the highlights work fine if I place the `highlighted = YES;` code inside viewDidLoad. But the above code does not work. The highlight doesn't stick. The buttons works, and does the other stuff it needs to do, but the highlights fail to stick.

I would think this should be pretty basic. Is iOS somehow automatically setting all button highlights to NO on its own after any button operation?

Comment: make sure that your first call in viewDidLoad is `[super viewDidLoad]`

Comment: What do you mean by "the highlights works fine no their own"? Is your problem, that you want to set a button highlighted at appearance of a view?

Comment: i mean, outside the context of a button press, the highlight setting works fine, such as when it is placed in viewDidLoad, the button comes up as highlighted. but inside the button action, the highlight setting does nothing.

Comment: so I completely misunderstood you. I thought it doesn't work in viewDidLoad. Maybe your IBAction doesn't get called.

Comment: the action is called and is doing all the other stuff it needs to do inside the `if` statement. but the highlights themselves do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should use other means to present the highlight status, because of the statement from `UIControl`'s documentation:

> By default, a control is not
>   highlighted. UIControl automatically
>   sets and clears this state
>   automatically when a touch enters and
>   exits during tracking and when there
>   is a touch up.

Comment: i wonder if this means that UIControl is affecting all highlight states for all buttons even if you only touch one of those buttons; as that is the experience I am having. I suspect I will need to do something similar to this: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=530998 though it is a shame to go to such lengths when all you want to do is manipulate a highlight

Comment: sure enough, it works like a charm by using the `selected` property instead of `highlight` and just changing the background image and title text color for the selected state.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the 'selected' property instead of the 'highlighted' property.